# Is it possible to make a JSONP request that gets back JSON data via a cross domain request using jQuery?

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I am using a jQuery Ajax call to query a cross domain URL that returns plain JSON data:

```
function getAlibrisSuggestions(theKeywords)
{
    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "http://www.alibris.com/cgi-bin/complete?site=18640838&mtype=B&term=" + encodeURI(theKeywords),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        /*  None of these helped obviously since the return is not JSONP but JSON
        complete: onSuggestionsFetched,
        beforeSend: onBeforeSend,
        success: onSuccess,
        dataFilter: onDataFilter,
        */
        });
}
```

Sample URL request:

```
http://www.alibris.com/cgi-bin/complete?site=18640838&mtype=B&term=book
```

The JSON response:

```
[
    {"l": "BP", "v": "books llc"},
    {"l": "BA", "v": "books time-life"},
    {"l": "BA", "v": "books general"},
    {"l": "BA", "v": "books sunset"},
    {"l": "BP", "v": "books on demand"},
    {"l": "BA", "v": "books golden"},
    {"l": "BA", "v": "books scholastic"},
    {"l": "BP", "v": "book jungle"},
    {"l": "BA", "v": "books chronicle"},
    {"l": "BP", "v": "booksurge publishing"}
]
```

Since it is cross domain I have to use JSONP to avoid origin errors.  The problem is, as you can see from the response from that URL, is that the return is plain JSON.  Since it is not formatted as Javascript, it results in jQuery returning a result status of "parsererror" and the expected "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred as MIME type text/plain" warning in Chrome's console.

I have no control over the foreign server.  I would like to avoid wrapping the call in a server side script just to dress up the return as Javascript.  Does anyone know of a clever way to be able to process the return?

-- roschler

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, sorry. Making a page on your server to forward the request is your best bet.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I was hoping that some clever soul figured out perhaps how to catch the Javascript warning when the DOM injection occurs or maybe have the injection misinterpreted as a call to an unreferenced Javascript function and catch that error, something weird like that.

Comment: The only hole that I know of that you could exploit is explained in John Resig's post here: http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/. However, that method doesn't work as of Firefox 3's release, so it's probably useless to you.