# jsonp jquery ajax call

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I'm in need of a code example here :/ I'm trying to get a jsonp call to work.

This is my code on jquery:

```
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain:true,
                url: "the_server_url",
                type: "POST",

                data: {
                    numberOfUnits:10,
                    unitType:"u",
                    language:"eng-us",
                    genderAndAge:"MiddleAgeAnyGender",
                    script:"",
                    synced_recording:0,
                    secret:0,
                    numAuditions:0
                },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(text) {
                    alert("Text: "+text);
                },
                error: function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("err: "+error);
                    alert ( " Can't do because: " + JSON.stringify(request));
                    alert("response text: "+request.responseText);
                }
            });
```

And this is what I get:

```
alert #1: err: parsererror
alert #2: Can't do because: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
alert #3: response text: undefined
```

I don't have access to the server code. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: consider to use the console for debugging purpose

Comment: This means the server doesn't support JSONP. It's sending back normal JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a JSONP request that gets back JSON data via a cross domain request using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434071/is-it-possible-to-make-a-jsonp-request-that-gets-back-json-data-via-a-cross-doma)

Comment: Yeah I guess is on the server side. Thank you :)